# Trajectory of a particle in a varying magnetic field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, charge

Let's say we have a particle of given mass 'm' and given charge 'q'. This particle enters a region of magnetic field which varies as
$$\ B = (k)\sin(wt)...(1)$$
where k and w are fixed constants and t is time.

The velocity of the particle, say V, is perpendicular to the magnetic field. At t = 0 the particle enters the influence of the magnetic force which is given by $\ Fmag = q(VXB)$, it executes circular motion and the radius of curvature can be found using the centripetal force
$$\ mV^2/R = Fmag....(2)$$
$$\ mV^2/R = q(VXB)...(3)$$
Since V and B are perpendicular, using equations (1), (2) and (3), we get
$$\ R = \frac{(mV)}{(q)(k)(\sin(wt))}$$

the radius of curvature varies with time

My question is, is this formula correct or am I missing something and if it is correct then will be the trajectory of this particle under the influence of this field and what will happen at $\ t = \frac{2n(\pi)}{w}$ , i.e., when the sine term becomes zero and radius of curvature tends to inifinity

Comment: But the changing magnetic field also generates electric field